# How to change the color background of ONE item of listView

Tags: android, listview

I want to change the color background of only **one** item of the listView, I currently have this:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(parentActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, accountList) {


      @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
              ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
              view.setLayoutParams(params);

              TextView textview = (TextView) view;
              textview.setTextSize(15);
              textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
              textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

              int p = 0;

               for (Accounts c : Register.getAccounts()) {
               if (c.getNumber().equals(accountNumber) && (position == p)){

                  view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

               }
          p++;
        }

   return textview;
   }
};

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Explanation:** I have a list of associated accounts owned by a user, I need to change the background color of the account that is active at that moment, the problem is that:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
```

Is setting more than one element of the listView, thank you.

Comment: Are you intending to increment `p` inside the for loop?

Comment: view.setbackground() is meaning that you're setting background to every view. I think you should get the element from adapter using getItem() method then set the background. I've not tried it yet but should be something like this `adapter.getitem(item).getview().setback....()`.

Comment: But then it should have colored all of them, but She says   `Is setting more than one element of the listView` which means at least not all of them @Simo

Comment: exactly that's what i"m saying. view.setbackground() is setting background to all the views. So even after checking for condition inside if() the background is set to all the view. It should be specific to the position of the view too.

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable p?

Comment: @Ophy why you looping inside Register.getAccounts() and why do not you just checking Register.getAccounts().get(position).equals(accountNumber) ??

Comment: Have you tried simply relying on the variable `accountNumber`?

Comment: What your code is doing is that for each list item its checks whether there exists an account number equal to _accountNumber_ (which probably always does) in the register and then it sets each list item's background .I think instead of looping you should try @AmirHosseinMirzaei solution

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei solution is not working, again is setting all the elements of the listView with the same color

Comment: @Ali That is not working

Comment: @Simio can you give me a better explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i changed your code try this

```
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(parentActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, accountList) {


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            view.setLayoutParams(params);

            TextView textview = (TextView) view;
            textview.setTextSize(15);
            textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


                if (Register.getAccounts().get(position).getNumber().equals(accountNumber) ){

                    textview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

                }else textview.setBackgroundResource(0);



            return textview;
        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting `p` and it's condition.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(parentActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, accountList) {


  @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
          view.setLayoutParams(params);

          TextView textview = (TextView) view;
          textview.setTextSize(15);
          textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
          textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

           if (Register.getAccounts().get(position).equals(accountNumber)){

              view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

           }

   return textview;
   }
};

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This is not working :/ 
Is setting **all** elements of listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "else" branch in your condition

```
if (c.getNumber().equals(accountNumber)){
   view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
} else {
  view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
}
```